# File not found exception. Text file in resources

Tags: java, eclipse, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to read a text file (dictionary.txt) which is located in `src/main/resources`, but I keep getting a file not found exception.

[image: where my text file is in package explorer]

```
public static <DoesWordExist> void DoesWordExist(int ReviewScore, String s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    HashSet<DoesWordExist> set = new HashSet<>();
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("/src/main/resources/dictionary/dictionary.txt"))){ // Reading dictionary
        if (set.contains (s)) { // Checking word is in dictionary
            
        }
        else {
            ReviewScore -= 5; // each word that d
        }
        System.out.println("Score is "+ ReviewScore);
    } 
}




    public static <DoesWordExist> void DoesWordExist(int ReviewScore, String s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
            HashSet<DoesWordExist> set = new HashSet<>();
             try (var resource = Review.class.getResourceAsStream("/dictionary/dictionary.txt")) {
                  Scanner sc = new Scanner(resource);{ // Reading dictionary
                if (set.contains (s)) { // Checking word is in dictionary
                    
                }
                else {
                    ReviewScore -= 5; // each word that is not found due to either typo or non-existence deduct 5pts
                }
                System.out.println("Score is "+ ReviewScore);
            } 
            //frequentlyUsedWords (ReviewScore,Review);
                
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`new File`. The name says it: That only works for **FILES**. Entries in jar files aren't themselves files.

If you write `new File`, or mention `FileInputStream`, you've lost. That cannot be made to work with this stuff.

Fortunately, you can just ask the JVM to give you a resource from the same place it loads class files, whereever those class files might be. In a jar, in a directory, live-loaded over a network - doesn't matter. You can get these resources in URL form and an InputStream form - any code that can work with those, can be made to work with 'resources that are in the same place my class files are, such as in the jar'.

Scanner is one of those things: It has a constructor that takes an inputstream. So, let's do that!

```
try (var resource = MyClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("/dictionary/dictionary.txt")) {
  Scanner s = new Scanner(resource);
  .. rest of code here
}
```

A few notes:

- `/dictionary/dictionary.txt` means: Relative to the 'root of the jar'. If you want relative to your class file's package, don't start with a leading slash.
- It's a resource, so it must be closed, hence, this code uses try-with-resources.

Comment: I tried this with exception but it says that the scanner variable is not being used. I used sc instead of 's' as you wrote because I already had a variable S. I've attached above

Comment: You still need to read the actual data. That's a bit too basic for SO. Learn to crawl before you learn to walk, start with a first principles java tutorial.

Comment: Hi, how would I read the data?

Comment: Google 'java read text file getResourceAsStream'.